# JavaScript in HTML "error" when sending request

Tags: javascript, json, coderunner

So, I made updates to this code to fix some issues that were pointed out in another question. The function runs, but returns {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}. I switched from $.getJSON to $.ajax so I could send headers to hopefully fix the error, but it's still giving me the same error without much detail.

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <title>Ecobee API PIN TEST</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function PINCode() {
            
            apiKey = 'kmkbJCrEUbMBpO2I6E90QeYcueAz1p00'
            
            // set all apiKey inputs to have apiKey value entered
            $(".apiKey").each(function() {
                $(this).val(apiKey);
            });
            
            var url = 'https://api.ecobee.com/authorize?response_type=ecobeePin&client_id=' + apiKey + '&scope=smartWrite';
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: url,
                headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#authCode").val(data.code);
                    alert("JSON Ran");
                    var response = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
                    $('#response1').html(response);
                }
            })
//            $.getJSON(url,function(data) {
//                // set authCode to be code attribute of response
//                $("#authCode").val(data.code);
//                alert("JSON Ran")
//                var response = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
//                $('#response1').html(response);
//            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                $('#response1').html("The following error was returned: <br><br>" + JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + "<p>Please Contact <b>M2 AV Consulting</b> at <a href=mailto:support@m2avc.com?subject='EcobeePINSupport'>support@m2avc.com</a>")
                console.log(textStatus);
            });
        })
    </script>
    <pre id="response1" class="code-json">(Response JSON will appear here...I hope.)</pre>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Look in your browser dev tools console and see if this is a CORS error. If it is you will need to use a proxy to make the request and keep your credentials from being exposed client side

Comment: Looks like it. This is what I'm getting:
[Error] Origin https://www.m2avconsulting.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.ecobee.com/authorize?response_type=ecobeePin&client_id=kmkbJCrEUbMBpO2I6E90QeYcueAz1p00&scope=smartWrite due to access control checks.
[Log] error (apis, line 333)
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://www.m2avconsulting.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (authorize, line 0)

Comment: Setting access control headers in the request is useless. They have to be set in response at the remote server. You will need to use a proxy either on server you control or third party service